# How can I group an array of objects by key using node typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

const cars = [
{
'make': 'audi',
'model': 'r8',
'year': '2012'
},{
'make': 'kia',
'model': 'optima',
'year': '2013'
},
];

const details = [
{
'make': 'audi',
'owner': 'user1',
'features': 'abc'
},{
'make': 'audi',
'owner': 'user2',
'features': 'xyz'
},
{
'make': 'kia',
'owner': 'user3',
'features': 'xyz'
},
{
'make': 'kia',
'owner': 'user4',
'features': 'xyz'
},
];

const result = [
{
'make': 'audi',
'model': 'r8',
'year': '2012',
"Details": [
{
'make': 'audi',
'owner': 'user1',
'features': 'abc'
},{
'make': 'audi',
'owner': 'user2',
'features': 'xyz'
}
]
},
{
'make': 'kia',
'model': 'optima',
'year': '2013',
"Details": [
{
'make': 'kia',
'owner': 'user3',
'features': 'xyz'
},
{
'make': 'kia',
'owner': 'user4',
'features': 'xyz'
},
]
},

];

Comment: E.g. Lodash [`keyBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#keyBy)

Comment: Take some time to read this before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: may be first format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to first group `details` array into a collection of `make -> [detail]`. Time complexity is O(n), and space complexity is also O(n) since we creating a new collection.

After that we can merge the new collection into cars array under the assumption that each `make` appears only once in the cars array (if not we will need a middleware step). Here time complexity is also O(n)

```
// group details collection
const groupDetails = details.reduce((m, detail) => {
    const items = m.get(detail.make) || [];
    m.set(detail.make, [ ...items, ...[detail] ]);
    return m;
}, new Map<string, unknown[]>());

// merge new collection into cars array
const carsDetails = cars.map(car => {
    const details = groupDetails.get(car.make) || [];
    return { ...car, ...{ Details: details }};
});
```

See running code example in [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAnCMC8MDaMDeMDkAtvANYCmeAXPvAK4AmAlngDT4Eh2kA2l%20iAHC3wBPUkl54ATAAYAjJLwwAvs1yES5KnmIN4Qwh24SQABygMi%200eK0zZAZkUqYAXQDcAKFCRYnKPAYuFHQsNSIyCVpGfRAAdzBSRAkaCETZfQAzMSgaRFIISIAjYCdVNg1I%20iZWPDiEpK0UxIUarPgcvIKtAA9hAC9SnHKIrR09GrrE5NTER1bs3PyJXoHlVjCK0d0Y%20KnGmYAWTIXO5f7B9w8vcGgYAHNEEBoTABFSf0DgmD8AoIA6PJ0GjAUgAClBBFYP0CAEo0AA%20HAeGAouA3WAMKCkAhfAh-O7vUHQrh-cKkOEAHwpmEuqJgeNSUCJ71%20pI0rCwfy5mOxEFYXL%20GGJLlcMM8dLyHTA9M8zgSsRgAFl4CYADzQRAMMB3Vg0MDEMB1DAueGgmFiq7eW4IRB0CBvD5BNBwJAQNkmUE2hFIulW3wsz7Oh5PV4B-4Epk2tlkSnU43i1GS3LS3ACm38rm4B2-CBUYkoJRKWUW66QEBcUh-LggO6gvCdGhcWCoIQ2u3Zz4WoA)

Comment: I didn't get exact out put[
  {
    make: 'audi',
    model: 'r8',
    year: '2012',
    Details: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    make: 'kia',
    model: 'optima',
    year: '2013',
    Details: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]

Comment: That's probably due to the way console.log is printing out the new array. Try `console.log('result =', JSON.stringify(cardsDetails));`